# How Do I load pthreads extension in CLI?

Tags: php, apache, pthreads

I have built both php and Apache from source on MAC OSX 10.11.

I have been having trouble loading pthreads extension in CLI.. I misunderstood how to load it and now I do not truly understand what should I do.

Here is what I have done so far.

I configured php with the following command:

```
'./configure' 
'--prefix=/Users/username/Terminal/WebServer'
'--with-apxs2=/Users/username/Terminal/WebServer/bin/apxs'
'--enable-maintainer-zts' 
'--enable-pthreads=shared' 
'--enable-debug' 
'--with-tsrm-pthreads' 
'--with-config-file-path=/Users/username/Terminal/WebServer/ini' 
'--enable-cli'
```

Apache's loaded Modules:

```
Compiled in modules:
  core.c
  mod_so.c
  http_core.c
  worker.c
```

So,  in /Users/username/Terminal/WebServer/ini directory I created `php-cli.ini` file and added `extension=pthreads.so` line, then I ran `php -m` command, the following is the output:

```
[PHP Modules]
Core
ctype
date
dom
fileinfo
filter
hash
iconv
json
libxml
pcre
PDO
pdo_sqlite
Phar
posix
<strong>pthreads</strong>
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
SPL
sqlite3
standard
tokenizer
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter

[Zend Modules]
```

I restarted Apache and opened `index.php` file which has `phpinfo()` in it.
**Notable information**

`Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /Users/username/Terminal/WebServer/ini`
`Loaded Configuration File => /Users/username/Terminal/WebServer/ini/php.ini`
`Scan this dir for additional .ini files => (none)`
`Additional .ini files parsed => (none)`
`Thread Safety => Enabled`

`phpinfo()` doens't include pthreads module information and I don't know whether it should or not.
at this point I open test.php file which includes the following pthreads script:

```
<?php $thread = new class extends Thread {
    public function run() {
        echo "Hello World\n";
    }
};

$thread->start() && $thread->join();
?>
```

and the output through apache is:

`Fatal error: Class 'Thread' not found in /Users/username/Sites/test.php on line 1`

When I run the following command on Terminal
`$ php /Users/username/Sites/test.php`

The output is : **Hello World**

**So the question is** how do I load pthreads extension in CLI properly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have the desired result, but don't seem to know why ...

The key parts of your configuration are:

### `configure` options

If PHP is being built with Apache DSO SAPI, you must use `--enable-pthreads=shared`, this causes the build process to create a DSO (shared object, dll in windows speak) from the pthreads library, rather than statically linking pthreads into the Apache DSO.

### `php.ini` configuration

From the PHP [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php):

> If php-SAPI.ini exists (where SAPI is the SAPI in use, so, for example, php-cli.ini or php-apache.ini), it is used instead of php.ini. The SAPI name can be determined with php_sapi_name().

Having built pthreads shared (pthreads.so), we can simply create `php-cli.ini` in the same path as `php.ini` and add `extension=pthreads.so` to it.

---

What you have works, however, it's not ideal; You don't really want Apache to use a PHP interpreter that has the overhead of ZTS.

Ideally, you will want to build and install PHP twice:

### First Build

`configure` `--with-apxs=...` `--disable-pthreads` `--prefix=/system/prefix` `--with-config-file-path=/system/prefix/etc` ...

*Replace `/system/prefix/` with sensible system prefix like `/usr/` ...*

When you `make install` this build, you will create the ideal installation for Apache, which includes a non-thread safe PHP binary at `/system/prefix/bin/php`, with all related scripts (`pecl`, `phpize`, `php-config` etc.) in `/system/prefix/bin`.

### Second Build

Before this build you need to `make clean` (if you are using a release tarball), or `vcsclean` (if you are using local git repository).

`configure --enable-maintainer-zts --enable-pthreads=static --prefix=/special/prefix --with-config-file-path=/special/prefix/etc` ...

*Replace `/special/prefix/` with sensible special prefix like `/opt/`, do not use the same prefix as the first build ...*

When you `make install` the first installation is not touched, instead a new installation is created without support for Apache, but with support for pthreads built statically into the binary (configuration free).

The binary will be at `/special/prefix/bin/php` with all related scripts in `/special/prefix/bin`.

### Wiring Builds Together

If both builds require the same PECL extensions with the exception of pthreads, you can use the same `--with-config-file-scan-dir` configure switch for both builds.

If you are really brave, you could use the same `--with-config-file-path` switch too, but this might have undesired results.

Editing `include_path` for both builds will also help.